# What structure involving Key and Value pair should be adopted when both Key and Value are repeated?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

**What structure involving Key and Value pair should be adopted when both Key and Value are repeated?**

**Scenario:**
I am generating an anonymous type in WPF this way

```
var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>()
                 .Select(x => new {Key = x, Value = (int)x});
```

I tried converting it to Dictionary using

```
.ToDictionary(Key => Key, Value => (int)Value);
```

**OR**

```
.ToDictionary(Key => (int)Key, Value => Value);
```

But in both cases it gives exception that **An item with the same key has already been added.** which means keys are repeated in both cases.

Now what structure should be adopted in this scenario? Should i go for `KeyValuepair<int, Key>[]` or anything other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I’d just stick with a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` but if you want a fancier interface you might want to write your own `MultiMap` wrapper class for that.

Of course, in neither case can you use `ToDictionary` since that uses the existing unique-key dictionary internally but you can write your own `ToMultiMap` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what structure should be adopted in this scenario?

Quite obviously and clearly stated in the documentation - NOT A DICTIONARY.

A list, an array, whatever, which fully depends on your usage patterns, not the creation patterns. As you do not say how you use that - well - the question can not be answered.

Alternatively you may use a Dictionary with a List of items - Key is unique, pointing to a List of values. Again, that depends - you may guess it by now - about how you USE The data.